# JMX java processes monitoring

Tags: java, monitoring, jmx

I work on JBoss 7 as and I want to monitor the JBoss processes:
 (memory used by this processes, CPU percentage...)
, using JMX features.
I try this code:

```
 Process p = Runtime.getRuntime().exec
                ("C:\\Users\\*****\\Downloads\\PSTools\\pslist -m");
Process p = Runtime.getRuntime().exec(
                    "C:\\Users\\olawzi\\Downloads\\PSTools\\pslist.exe -s 2");
```

and it gives a good result,
but it doesn't a JMX way.
I want to use JMX.
Is there any way to do this?
thanks for everyone...

Comment: have you tried checking http://localhost:8080/jmx-console/ , or mbeans

Comment: it give me this error: description The requested resource (/jmx-console) is not available.

Comment: did you mean :127.0.0.1:9990/console/App.html#server-overview ??

Comment: Even if you want to develop you own client, or you want jconsole or some other type of client, you can start by reading the basic introduction available at http://docs.oracle.com/javase/tutorial/jmx. If you then decide on a specific solution you can come back and edit your question focusing on what you're really having trouble with.

Answer (score 0):

Well you can use Nagios to monitor JBoss and other processes very efficiently.You just need a jmx plugin and mbean class which are already [here](https://sourceforge.net/projects/jboss2nagios/?source=typ_redirect)

Integrate JBoss into Nagios monitoring through a small Collector MBean and a perl based Nagios plugin. Lets you read and monitor JMX values from JBoss servers very efficiently. On the Nagios server no JDK or JBoss installation is needed.
[image]

> **Installation**:
>
> with JBoss:
>
> Copy the collector.sar (from the mbean/ directory) to your JBoss
>   deploy directory. Port 5566 is then open for the plugin to access it.
>   with Tomcat or anything else:
>
> Put the collector.sar somewhere in the file system and add
>   -javaagent:/path/to/collector.sar to the options of the JVM you want to monitor. Nagios server:
>
> Copy the plugin check_mbean_collector (from the plugin/ directory) to
>   the Nagios plugin directory on the Nagios server. Edit your Nagios
>   config to use the check_mbean_collector to monitor any attributes of
>   any MBean. You might check that the plugin and the MBean is working
>   properly by doing a test run on the Nagios server:

```
./check_mbean_collector -H jbossserver -p 5566 -m jboss.system:type=ServerInfo -a ActiveThreadCount -w 200 -c 400<p>
```

The benefit of using nagios is that:
you dont have to write customized mbeans everytime.
thousands of ready made plugins.
whole lot of distributed processes can be monitored with very less effort from a centralized server.
And ofcourse community support.

**Note**: You may install nagios from [here](https://www.digitalocean.com/community/tutorials/how-to-install-nagios-4-and-monitor-your-servers-on-ubuntu-14-04) However if you dont want to install nrpe and nagios then use op5 monitor and check_jmx plugin.you may then simply use it like

```
./check_jmx -U service:jmx:rmi:///jndi/rmi://'app-server':'1090'/jmxrmi -O jboss.jca:name=JmsXA,service=ManagedConnectionPool -A AvailableConnectionCount
```